# How can a custom jinja2 tag interface with the context of a flask request

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, contextmanager

I'm writing a custom [`jinja2` extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370542/jinja2-extension-outputs-escaped-html-instead-of-html-tag/29378286#29378286) to use in `flask` applications and I'm looking for a way to access the templates context data using the tag I'm implementing. That is, I want the extension tag to use context params passed into the template:

```
@app.route('/users/<user_id>')
def user_page(user_id):
    ...
    return render_template('users/index.html', user_id=user_id, active=True)
```

The template:

```
<!-- I want this tag to see the value of user_id and active -->
{% my_jinja2_tag %}
```

I know I can render the context variable using `{{ user_id }}`, but what I'm looking for is a way to inspect the context of the template rendering a custom jinja2 extension. Is that doable? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ContextReference

Yes, it's possible using `jinja2.nodes.ContextReference()`. See the API reference [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#jinja2.nodes.ContextReference).

Relax, I'm going to guide you through it. :)

First the extension:

```
class ActiveCheckerExtension(jinja2.ext.Extension):
    """
    This will give us a {% check_active %} tag.
    """

    template = 'Active is : %s'
    tags = set(['check_active'])

    def _render_tag(self, context, caller):
        return jinja2.Markup(self.template % unicode(context['active']))

    def parse(self, parser):
        ctx_ref = jinja2.nodes.ContextReference()
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno
        node = self.call_method('_render_tag', [ctx_ref], lineno=lineno)
        return jinja2.nodes.CallBlock(node, [], [], [], lineno=lineno)
```

Then let's add it to Flask's jinja2.

```
app.jinja_env.add_extension(ActiveCheckerExtension)
```

Now in your template, you can do:

```
{% check_active %}
```

Make sure `active` is defined in all the templates you add the tag to, or else you'll get a `KeyError` because the context won't have that template variable.